# Why is this thin black line showing in play mode but not in scene view in Unity 3D engine

Tags: unity-game-engine

Please take a look at screenshot

[image]

I want to hide those thin black lines in my game.

Comment: Those lines are most likely to be rendered in the view because you're using asset tiles for your grass road and there are tiny slits between the tiles. Those slits are not shown in scene view probably because the parameters of your camera in scene view and game view are different. If you somehow manage your scene view camera to have parameters close to the ones of game view camera, you should be able to see the lines. Actually you can see some of them on the far end of the road in your screen shot, even in your scene view.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid them by enabling `Pixel Snap` in the Material of the tiles. Try also by turning off Anti aliasing in `Projects Settings > Quality`.

Comment: They still exist but they aren't visible as before